# Why won't my program open on Pocket PC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I am making a program in Visual Studio 2008 for my Pocket PC, but I can't get the program to open. I followed the instructions to create a cab file to install it on the device, but then when I try to click on the program its loads for half a second and then doesn't do anything. The program works fine in the emulator.

Comment: Can you include the current version of your code that shows this issue?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the code. Its just a button that makes a variable increment and then displays in a text box. I found out that if I deploy the solution directly to the device it works fine, just not when its through cab.

Comment: Not too much info about the prog. If it is a MFC one and uses MFC in shared lib, it would run from VS but not when only the exe is deployed without MFC runtimes. Possibly you can add more details (ie the project file and the cab inf file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really using a Pocket PC device?  The Pocket PC terminology was last used in 2003.  The platform has been called "Windows Mobile" since then.  Not to be confused with "Windows 10 Mobile".  Naming is not a strong point for Microsoft in this regard.

You need to use the Pocket PC SDK if you are truly developing for a Pocket PC.

If your application uses MFC then your program will depend on the MFC library to run. The simplest way to solve this problem is to link statically to MFC.

1. Go to the Project Settings
2. Go to the "General" tag page.
3. Search for "Use of MFC" and select "Use MFC in a static library".
4. Save & Rebuild the project.  The size of your EXE is now larger because you have statically linked to MFC.

If your application uses Compact Framework then your program will also depend on the .NET Compact Framework (CF) library to run.  The simplest way to solve this problem is to include the CAB file(s) from your Visual Studio folder.  Then you can run the CAB file to install .NET Compact Framework.

1. Navigate to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce400\armv4" folder.
2. Copy the "NETCFv2.ppc.armv4.cab" file to your device.
3. On the device, navigate to the NETCFv2.ppc.armv4.cab file and click on it to install.

You can read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788171(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Yes I am trying to make things for for my Pocket PC running "Windows Mobile 2003". In visual studio 2008 I am selecting "Pocket PC 2003" for my smart device project's target platform. I am only just learning how to use visual studios, so I don't really understand what your options mean; could you put that into normal people words?

Comment: Also it runs fine on the device when I deploy solution directly to the device, but then it looks like its also adding two programs called "Microsoft .NET CF 2.0" and "Microsoft .NET CF 2.0 ENU-String ..." which its not doing if I try installing via cab file. I would like it to be able to run with just the cab file on a factory new settings device.

Comment: The Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 must be installed for your application to run.  Visual Studio does this for you when you press F5.  It also copies the MFC/CRT DLLs for you.  That explains why it works for you when you Debug or press F5.

Comment: You can press F5 to let Visual Studio push the files to the device.  Then you can go on the device and grab the files.  They are usually starting with 
MS and ending with the file extension DLL.  Then just follow the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to include the armv4.cab with my projects cab file and have it automatically install the armv4.cab when my project cab file is installed?

Comment: It's a very common request, but the answer is no.  If your goal is to automate the installation of your software then you should research CABWIZ and write a simple program that installs the CAB files in the correct order using CABWIZ.  

If you're using a popular rugged device like Motorola/Symbol/Intermec/Honeywell then they most likely already have a tool installed to handle CAB file installation that you can hook into.